# Can't get past this error with anchor/@coral/xyz

Tags: solana-program, anchor-lang

```
import { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { Program, setProvider, web3, AnchorProvider } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { NodeStringSaver, IDL } from "../target/types/node_string_saver";
import "dotenv/config";
import NodeWallet from "@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/nodewallet";
import { bs58 } from "@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/utils/bytes";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
const program = new Program<NodeStringSaver>(
  IDL,
  new PublicKey("LwLEiVLfLitKwkTSo6rScZspxTF1PfeEX8HBp71LCHE"),
  {
    connection,
  }
);
const keyPair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
  bs58.decode(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY ?? "")
);

const wallet = new NodeWallet(keyPair);

const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {
  commitment: "processed",
});
setProvider(provider);

const start = async () => {
  const myAccount = web3.Keypair.generate();

  await program.methods
    .initialize("Users")
    .accounts({
      stringHolder: myAccount.publicKey,
      signer: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
    })
    .signers([myAccount])
    .rpc();
  console.log(await program.account.stringHolder.all());
};

start();
```

and this is my error
Error: This function requires 'Provider.sendAndConfirm' to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about this error, but you can still send the transaction manually if you're stucked. Instead of using .rpc(), just create a new Transaction(), add your instruction, blockhash and feepayer, sign it and send it.

If you don't know how to do that, let me know, i will post some code to show you

Comment: Didn't know that thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You used `{ connection: Connection }` for the 3rd param of Program constructor which is derived from `Provider` interface.
`AnchorProvider` is also derived from `Provider` and it has NodeWallet and it has `sendAndConfirm` function implemented.
When you use program.methods().rpc() it tries to use `Provider` instance which it does not have `sendAndConfirm` implemented.

Here you get the updated code:

```
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
const keyPair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
  bs58.decode(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY ?? "")
);
const wallet = new NodeWallet(keyPair);
const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {
  commitment: "processed",
});
setProvider(provider);
const program = new Program<NodeStringSaver>(
  IDL,
  new PublicKey("LwLEiVLfLitKwkTSo6rScZspxTF1PfeEX8HBp71LCHE"),
  provider,
);
```